# ValueError: weights should have the same shape as x

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my code

```
    from __future__ import division
    import sys
    import math
    import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def get_pt_t(event):
        pt_list=[]
        pdg_list=[]
        for particle in event:
            p = FourMomentum()
            if particle.pid in [-11,11,13,-13] and particle.status==1 :
                p += particle
                pt_list.append(p.pt)
                break
        return pt_list
values_x= []

PT_t=[]
PT_t.append(pt_list)
```

...

now,pt_list holds a list ie like [x,y] for each "particle" above- Now, while trying to draw

```
nbins=300
# prepare the plots
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[5,1.2])
gs1.update(wspace=0, hspace=0) # set the spacing between axes.

# plot the Three main curve for the pt
ax = plt.subplot(gs1[0])
wgts_list = []
wgts_list.append( [1,2])
n3, nbins, _ = ax.hist(PT_t, bins=nbins, histtype='step', linewidth=0,weights=wgts_list)
```

but I get

```
n3, nbins, _ = ax.hist(PT_t, bins=nbins, histtype='step', linewidth=0,weights=wgts_list)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8290, in hist
    raise ValueError('weights should have the same shape as x')
ValueError: weights should have the same shape as x
```

I think the problem is that I want to draw a list (PT_t) but cannot assign a weights list in the weights argument though..

Comment: How long is your `PT_t` list (what is returned by `len(PT_t)`? Your `wgts_list` is a list of two elements. The error you're getting is telling you they should be the same length.